# camera takes picture where it temporary save picture in android?

Tags: android, camera

i m working on project and requirements of the project is to **do some action if camera takes any picture** any suggestions on how can i do this......

this issue is solvable but it need your help so please give any suggestions 
 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#ACTION_NEW_PICTURE
this link is not have any help about my question

Comment: If you need the location of the photo taken then the documentation you linked states that: "getData() is URI of the picture".

Answer (score 0):

use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, pathToSave);
startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PIC);
```

and

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    switch (requestCode) {
    case TAKE_PIC:
            //Do with the "pathToSave" what you want
```

Comment: in this situation the our code will take pic and return .but i want just to only to check whether the picture is taken with any camera app and then do some action.